# How to use the R version specified in the lock file to build the Image/environment

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, renv

I'm using this great **renv package** to manage my R applications dependencies in the Docker File.As you can see, in the renv.lock file that specifies the packages versions and dependencies, it also mentions the R version.

```
{
  "R": {
    "Version": "4.2.3",
    "Repositories": [
      {
        "Name": "CRAN",
        "URL": "https://cloud.r-project.org"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Packages":
    "BH": {
      "Package": "BH",
      "Version": "1.81.0-1",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "68122010f01c4dcfbe58ce7112f2433d"
    },
    "DBI": {
      "Package": "DBI",
      "Version": "1.1.3",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Requirements": [
        "R",
        "methods"
      ],
    ...
```

How can I force my Image or my R environment to use the R specified in the renv.lock ?
Here is the code for the docker image.

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:20.04

## update system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean

# copy necessary files
## renv.lock file
COPY /my-app/renv.lock ./renv.lock
## app folder
COPY /my-app ./app
WORKDIR /app

# expose port
EXPOSE 8080

# install renv & restore packages
WORKDIR /app

RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("renv")'
RUN Rscript -e 'renv::restore()'
```

Comment: What about `FROM rocker/r-ver:4.2.3` to install a fixed version of R? This builds off the base `ubuntu` image.

Comment: Thank you. I know that and it doesn't help. I want the version to be picked up automatically from renv.lock file